# scalac for Call-by-Name use references

Tags: scala, bytecode, scalac

I have some function:

```
def f(x: Int) = x * x
```

and then I call it:

```
var y = 0
f { y += 1; y }
```

Bytecode generated for above code looks like:

```
     0: iconst_0      
     1: istore_1      
     2: aload_0       
     3: iload_1       
     4: iconst_1      
     5: iadd          
     6: istore_1      
     7: iload_1       
     8: invokevirtual #18                 // Method f:(I)I
    11: pop           
    12: return
```

If I change function **def f(x: Int)** to represent Call-by-Name:

```
def f(x: => Int) = x * x
```

generated bytecode for the same part of code looks like:

```
     0: new           #24                 // class scala/runtime/IntRef
     3: dup           
     4: iconst_0      
     5: invokespecial #28                 // Method scala/runtime/IntRef."<init>":(I)V
     8: astore_1      
     9: aload_0
     ....
```

My question is:

Is it a rule that for Call-by-Name we oparate on references or it depends on semantic analysis phase in compilation?

Comment: What's the question? The compiler knows everything there is to know about the types in your program and (barring compiler bugs) generates code that captures those types and their semantics.

Comment: I would like to understand the case (sorry If I miss something). So the compiler analyze the whole block var y = 0
f { y += 1; y } and based on that use proper type?

Comment: Of course. That's what compilers do.

Comment: I updated the question. Should be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual parameters to by-name formal parameters are always packaged into a so-called "thunk" (the terminology goes all the way back to Algol in the 1960s) which makes it possible for there to be zero, one or more (any number) of evaluations of the *expression* that comprises the actual argument. The bit about multiple evaluations is significant if there are side-effects in that expression.

The specific use of that "reference" has to do with the fact that code that will execute in the called function will have a side-effect on a local variable (literally, specifically a `var`) in the *calling* method. That is why the `IntRef` is involved. A "ref" of one sort or another (depending on the type of the `var` that gets referenced in the actual parameter expression) will always be used in that circumstance. If no `var` is involved, the value is simply copied to the thunk.